# How can I remove tags from a list scraped with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm extracting the "title" of a page scraped with beautifulsoup by looking for the tags:

```
title = [text.find_all('h1', {'class', 'entry-title'}) for text in texts]
```

the output is list with something like that:

```
[[<h1 class="entry-title">Receita de pão caseiro fácil para iniciantes</h1>],
 [<h1 class="entry-title">Pão branco com fermentação natural</h1>],... etc]
```

I want to remove  and  from the list

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
title = []
for text in texts:
    temp=[]
    for texData in text.find_all('h1', attrs = {'class': 'entry-title'}):
        temp.append(texData.get_text())
    title.append(temp)
```

Comment: For long term value, please add an explanation to your code. SO frowns on code only Answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the extract() or decompose() functions.

Comment: first you should search and try to do it. If you have problems , you should post the code

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to do that with for loop like it was in the documentation but i didn't work. Can you show some exemple in how to use this functions?

Comment: Alejandro Gonzalez, I tried with those function mecioned by Micheal Macaulay and tried using RegEx but it didn't work!